# Discrepancy in number of upgradable packages between apt-get and Update manager

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I ran the command `apt-get update && apt-get -s upgrade | grep 'upgraded'` and was displayed the output below.

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
31 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Now below is a screenshot of what the update manager displays

[image: Upgrade manager shows upgrade count 37.]

So based on the preceding output I have a total of 34 packages. Does this mean that NEW packages are not attributed towards the count of `31 upgraded` and `3 not upgraded` because as show below there are what I *think* to be an additional 3 packages hence bringing the total to 37.

```
linux-headers-3.2.0-25
linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
```

**Questions**

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. If it is correct why then do the 3 packages not appear under the count of `newly installed`?

I am using Ubuntu LTS 12.04

Comment: Try `apt-get dist-upgrade` and see what it shows you.

Comment: Also, make sure you have updated the package list in the Update manager so it's not just showing a cached value.

Comment: @Daniel Andersson - I only noticed the discrepancy *after* I had run `apt-get dist-upgrade` so can't now see the difference. I did however update the list in Update Manager and it still showed 37.